# How do you find a random open port in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

If you call `DRb.start_service(nil, some_obj)` and then `DRb.uri`, you get back the local URI, including a port number, that another process can use to make calls.

I'm looking to just have some code find a random available port and return that port number, instead of starting up a full-fledged `DRb` service. Is there a simple way to do this in Ruby?

Answer (score 21):

Haven't tried it, but this may work.

From http://wiki.tcl.tk/2230

> The process can let the system
>   automatically assign a port.  For
>   both the Internet domain and the XNS
>   domain, specifying a port    number of
>   0 before calling bind() requests the
>   system to do this.

Also see http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/socket/rdoc/classes/Socket.html#M003723

```
 require 'socket'

 # use Addrinfo
 socket = Socket.new(:INET, :STREAM, 0)
 socket.bind(Addrinfo.tcp("127.0.0.1", 0))
 p socket.local_address #=> #<Addrinfo: 127.0.0.1:2222 TCP>
```

Note the use port 0 in socket.bind call. Expected behavior is the local_address will contain the random open port.

Comment: Be advised! This does not work under `rbx-2.5.2` ... `Addrinfo` is nowhere to be found.

Comment: `socket.local_address.inspect_sockaddr` returns a plain string like `"127.0.0.1:2222"`

Answer (score 1):

You can try [random-port](https://github.com/yegor256/random-port), a simple Ruby gem (I'm the author):

```
require 'random-port'
port = RandomPort::Pool.new.acquire
```

The best way, though, is to use the block:

```
RandomPort::Pool.new.acquire do |port|
  # Use the port, it will be returned back
  # to the pool afterward.
end
```

The pool is thread-safe and guarantees that the port won't be used by another thread or anywhere else in the app, until it's released.